# What should be done with the [sports] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a [sports](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) tag which encompasses everything about both sport and fitness. However, sports generally describe competitive activities (practiced either alone or with  a team) whereas fitness is not necessarily competitive. The tag is currently applied to several questions about fitness in a non-competitive context. Here's one example:

- [Are there any specifics related to veganism and working out?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/482/are-there-any-specifics-related-to-veganism-and-working-out)

Should the tag be renamed? Should an additional tag be created? Can this be solved in satisfactory way just by modifying the tag guidance? The tag is currently used on 8 questions.

Comment: I had thought this was just a USian English thing... I had the idea that *sports* meant any kind of exercise activity to some speakers. "Sports" as such seems not even really on topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think retaining it as just [sports](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) allows for questions like vegan sports equipment (balls may be made with leather, for example, and how can a vegan identify that?), whereas [sport-fitness](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport-fitness) is just about the exercise/fitness aspect. Two distinct tags which often co-tag questions may be appropriate.

Comment: To clarify, are you suggesting creation of a new [fitness] tag?

Comment: Yes -- there's often crossover between sports and fitness, but I feel like they're still distinct concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tag should be renamed to [sports-fitness](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports-fitness) in order to encompass both sport and non-competitive fitness, while recognizing that there is a strong overlap between sport and fitness.